# Typescript error TS2095: Could not find symbol 'module'

Tags: angularjs, typescript, jasmine

I have a **AngularJS** app. I am writing its unit test using **jasmine** (run by karma) in **typescript**. Below is a simplified snippet of my unit-test:

```
///<reference path="../typings/angularjs/angular.d.ts" />
///<reference path="../typings/jasmine/jasmine.d.ts" />

describe('ABC', () => {
    var abc : any;
    var $httpBackend : any;

    beforeEach(() => {
        module('xyz');

        inject((_abc_, _$httpBackend_) => {
            abc = _abc_;
            $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
        });
    });
});
```

When I do grunt build, I am getting following errors:

```
error TS2095: Could not find symbol 'module'.
error TS2095: Could not find symbol 'inject'.
```

Where am I going wrong? I have added typing for angular, but still it is not getting recognised. Note that by adding jasmine typing, `describe`, `beforeEach` etc. are recognised by the typescript compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution - added `angularjs / angular-mocks.d.ts` typing and it worked.

```
///<reference path="../../../typings/angularjs/angular-mocks.d.ts" />
```